what could be the reason of the NTP "when" increasing over "poll"?
I have a NTP server with a "poll" time of 1024. Frequently the "when"  time exceeds the poll time. As I understand it, when shows the time since the last poll and the poll time shows the frequency of polling.
Shouldn't "when" always be smaller than or equal to "poll"?


The when column shows the last time a packet was received from the peer (ref: https://www.ntp.org/documentation/4.2.8-series/ntpq/#control-message-commands - under the peer command).  If a packet was lost for any reason (keep in mind that NTP uses UDP, so there are no retries), then when will show a higher value than poll.  If the condition persists, ntpd should automatically start dropping poll to correct the situation, or in the case of using a pool, query DNS for a new peer.
As an aside, you only have 1 peer configured, so you're at the mercy of that peer's network connectivity, as well as anything in between you and them.  NTP Best Current Practice (RFC 8633) recommends a minimum of 4 peers for reliable timekeeping.
